# Filter/Exclude xPath extraction via "pattern"

Tags: xpath

This is what I have to work with:

```
<div class="Pictures zoom">

<a title="Productname 1" class="zoomThumbActive" rel="{gallery: 'gallery1', smallimage: '/images/2.24198/little_one.jpeg', largeimage: '/images/76.24561/big-one-picture.jpeg'}" href="javascript:void(0)" style="border-width:inherit;">

<img title="Productname 1" src="/images/24.245/mini-doge-picture.jpeg" alt="" /></a>

<a title="Productname 1" rel="{gallery: 'gallery1', smallimage: '/images/2.24203/small_one.jpeg', largeimage: '/images/9.5664/very-big-one-picture.jpeg'}" href="javascript:void(0)" style="border-width:inherit;">

<img title="Productname 1" src="/images/22.999/this-picture-is-very-small.jpeg" alt="" /></a>

<div>
```

Using following Xpath:

```
/html//div[@class='Pictures zoom']/a/@rel
```

The output becomes:

```
{gallery: 'gallery1', smallimage: '/images/2.24198/little_one.jpeg', largeimage: '/images/76.24561/big-one-picture.jpeg'}
{gallery: 'gallery1', smallimage: '/images/2.24203/small_one.jpeg', largeimage: '/images/9.5664/very-big-one-picture.jpeg'}
```

Is it possible to filter the extraction, so intread of above, I only get these:

```
/images/76.24561/big-one-picture.jpeg
/images/9.5664/very-big-one-picture.jpeg
```

I only wish to keep everything between `largeimage: '` and `'}`

Best regards,

Liu Kang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substring-before` and `substring-after` to cut of the parts you do not want.

Using **XPath 1.0**, this can only be done for single results (so you cannot fetch all URLs contained in one document with a single XPath call). This query will return the first URL:

```
substring-before(substring-after((//@rel)[1], "largeimage: '"), "'")
```

**XPath 2.0** allows you to run functions as axis steps. This query will return *all* URLs you're looking for as single tokens:

```
//@rel/substring-before(substring-after(., "largeimage: '"), "'")
```

Comment: Sadly, I cannot use XPath 2.0, but this is perfect for me. Thanks!